# Laravel 8 Inner Join Two Tables

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm trying to get different columns from two tables in my Laravel database, I'm new to joins but following the docs I think my syntax is correct, except I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'created_at' in on clause is ambiguous (SQL: select `data_source_one`.`event_count`, `data_source_two`.`sessions` from `data_source_one` inner join `data_source_two` on `created_at` >= `2021-01-11 10:57:45`)
```

I have two tables:

- data_source_one
- data_source_two

Each table has the Laravel `created_at` column, one table has a `sessions` column, the other has `event_count`, and I have data for 14 days prior to my query. So not sure why it can't get the data?

My PHP is:

```php
public function getSources(Request $request)
{

    $data = DB::table('data_source_one')
          ->join('data_source_two', 'created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(14))
          ->select('data_source_one.event_count', 'data_source_two.sessions')
          ->get();

    return response()->json($data, 200);

}
```

Comment: created_at exists in both tables, so you must add the table like this:data_source_two.created_at

Comment: It says that the `created_at` column doesn't exist when I have `->join('data_source_two.created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(14))`, it does exist though

Comment: anyway, it looks to me like you are using the on statement as where statement...

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the error message, the "created_at" column is ambiguous because it's present in both tables.
So you have to specify which "created_at" you are referring to.

Maybe like this:

```
$data = DB::table('data_source_one as DSO')
      ->join('data_source_two as DST', //here, join your two tables by a common column )
      ->select('DSO.event_count', 'DST.sessions')
      ->where('DST.created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(14))
      ->get();
```

Comment: Weirdly this returns the error: `Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '2021-01-11 11:12:21'` as if it's using the value for the column name?

Comment: @RyanHolton thats not weird, the on statement should be used to make the relation work, you want to use it as where statement. Do you have a local and foreign key in the tables?

Comment: @RyanHolton Yes, because you are using a join as where.
You must join your two tables by a common column, and then add the where clause like this : ->where('DST.created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(14))

Comment: Both tables have the default `id` column, other than this, I only have the `created_at` and `updated_at` as being the same per table. So trying to do: `->join('data_source_two as DST', 'id')`, why wouldn't this work? can I not use the `id` column?

Comment: Every angle I attack this from I get some kind of `Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column COLUMN NAME in on clause is ambiguous `

Comment: @RyanHolton Each time you call a column from table1 with exactly the same name as a column from table2, you must precede this column by the name of its table to avoid any ambiguity.
There, your error message indicates that your tables both have a name column, you must precede this column by the name of its table. Like this:
-> join ('data_source_two as DST', DST.name ',' = ',' DSO.name ')